# Which grunt module was used to combine these files?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I found an old project which was using grunt to build and minify many JS files. The JS files, along with the code, have these '@include' annotations which signals which JS files should be included there, e.g:

```
//@include include/_extend-namespace.js
//@include lib/_modernizr.js
//@include include/_init-media-query.js
//@include controllers/_signup.js

var forcePinToTop = false;
var enableScrollButtonMovement = false;
var pTopVal;
var pLeftVal;
...
```

Can you help me identify which module was used for this purpose?

All modules I found use configuration to specify how to combine files, but it's not the case here where you only specify the top JS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this one?: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-preprocess

Very hard to know...

Best way is to look to package.json or grunt configuration files

Comment: Thanks, will try. Unfortunately, I don't have any package.json / configuration files, only the source files.

Comment: Just tried and it works, thanks! I don't have reputation so I cannot upvote your answer.

Comment: That is great, glad to help. Btw you can mark the answer as accepted :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [grunt-preprocess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-preprocess), which is a wrapper over [preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/preprocess#all-directives). The code that actually does the including is [here](https://github.com/jsoverson/preprocess/blob/master/lib/preprocess.js#L338). Assuming no other conflicting config, you should be able to change those to `require` or `import` with a little bit of sed/vim/regex find and replace.

Comment: Just tried and it works, thanks! I don't have reputation so I cannot upvote your answer.

Comment: @dejoslav I don't care about the reputation from upvotes, but could you [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the checkmark under the arrows? This helps with filtering and moderation queues for other users.